# How do I organize structure of my testSuite using beforeClass, afterClass, afterSuite in testNG?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, webdriver, testng

I m confused about using annotations @beforeClass,afterClass, beforeSuite,afterSuite in testNG.

I understand test structure below:

```
package mytestNG.learning.it ;

public class sample_not_working {
  @Test
  //take action - click on links, input data etc
  public void main() {
  }
  @BeforeMethod
  //do stuff like setup browser etc
  public void beforeMethod() {
  }

  @AfterMethod
  //close browser 
  public void afterMethod() {
  }
}
```

But what do you do in beforeclass,afterClass and test? What file is it? 
Is it a class that runs other classes?

Next, afterSuite, beforeSuite and **@test** :

```
  public class sample_not_working {
  @Test

  public void main() {
  //WHAT KINDA CODE YOU PUT HERE?
  }
  @BeforeSuite
  //WHAT KINDA CODE YOU PUT HERE?
  public void beforeMethod() {
  }
  @AfterSuite
  public void afterMethod() {
  //WHAT KINDA CODE YOU PUT HERE?
  }
}
```

My question is about semantics, the meaning, not actual code. I read the testNG docs - did not help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following testng.xml:

```
<suite name="MySuite">
  <test name="MyBigTest">
    <classes>
      <class name="test.sample.firstTestClass"/>
        <methods>
          <include name="a" />
          <include name="b" />
        </methods>
      <class name="test.sample.secondTestClass"/>
        <methods>
          <include name="c" />
          <include name="d" />
        </methods>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Then...

- @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite will run before/after **MySuite**
- @BeforeTest and @AfterTest will run before/after **MyBigTest**
- @BeforeClass and @AfterClass will run before/after **firstTestClass** and **secondTestClass**
- @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod will run before/after **a, b, c** and **d** methods

For example you can set up your environment in @BeforeSuite or you can use @BeforeTest to open a browser and at the end of the testmethods you can close it by using @AfterTest, etc...

Answer (score 0):

That's really depend on what are you testing and how you are doing it. I usually put drivers in @BeforeSuite and i quit them in @AfterSuite.

in @AfterClass (if im using it) i'm placing logs for whole class [about fields] and for example change value of some variables.

in @BeforeClass i sometimes initialize variables/fields.

But in the end, thoes annotation are for helping you and they have been created for easily executed your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to understad it using below example. It does not have @AfterClass / @BeforeClass. But it helps to understand structure.

```
package com.kagrana.base;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Optional;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import com.kagrana.DTO.TestCase;
import com.kagrana.DTO.WebDriverConfig;
import com.kagrana.util.Log;

public abstract class BaseActions {
    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected static Log log;
    protected WebDriverConfig config;
    protected String baseURL;
    protected TestCase testCase;
    private static int testCaseCount = 1;

    /**
     * This gets invoked even before suite starts.
     * @param ReportLocation
     */
    @Parameters({"ReportLocation"})
    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite(@Optional String ReportLocation){
        log = new Log();
    }
    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters({ "remoteURL", "baseURL", "OS", "browser",
            "version", "internal" })
    public void beforeTest(String remoteURL, String baseURL,
            String OS, String browser, String version, String internal)
            throws IOException {
        this.testCase = new TestCase();
        this.testCase.setExecutionEnvironment("{browser:"+browser+",browserVersion:"+version+",OperatingSystem:"+OS+"}");
        this.testCase.setParentURL(baseURL);
        this.testCase.setTestCaseId("KT"+testCaseCount++);
        this.testCase.setScreenshotDirectory(log.getReportDirectory()+"\\images");
        config = new WebDriverConfig();
        config.setRemoteURL(remoteURL);
        this.baseURL = baseURL;
        config.setOS(OS);
        config.setBrowserName(browser);
        config.setBrowserVersion(version);
        config.setIntenal(Boolean.parseBoolean(internal));
        driver = xRemoteWebDriver.getInstance(config, log);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(this.baseURL);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterTest(ITestResult itr) {
        testCase.setExecutionTime((itr.getEndMillis() - itr.getStartMillis()));
        testCase.setTestCaseName(itr.getName());
        log.addTestCase(testCase);
        try {
            driver.close();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {

        }
        try {
            driver.quit();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {

        }
    }
    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuite(ITestContext itc) throws IOException{
        log.setTestSuiteName(itc.getSuite().getName());
        log.writeReport();
        log.zipAndEmailFile();
    }

}
```

Source: https://github.com/selenium-webdriver-software-testing/kspl-selenium-helper/blob/master/src/main/java/in/mayurshah/base/BaseActions.java

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time people use  `@BeforeMethod` and  `@AfterMethod` for setup and tearing down driver.

For this and other common automation needs, there are TestNG extensions available to [use Selenium](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#use-selenium) with TestNG that provides such implementation inbuilt. For example, one of the framework abstracting [driver management outside the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148345/selenium-java-browser-session-reuse/40400187#40400187) so you test and related code be neat and clean and you don't need to worry about driver management and other common automation needs for web or mobile automation.